# (IONIC 4) ion-tab-button do not change color when clicked/selected

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have an `ion-tab` with differents ways to redirect: By Routes at the `tabs.module.ts` and by `[routerLink]` in html.

The problem is: when the `ion-tab-buttons` are clicked, they navigate to other pages correctly but the color only change when using Routes and "loadchildren" routing.

using CSS:

```
ion-tab-button {
 --color-selected: var(--ion-color-text-secondary);
}
```

I tried to use `loadChildren` routing in all tabs but some tabs are to redirect to a component and was not successful. 
I also tried to use pseudo-classes in CSS like

```
ion-tab-button:active {
    color: blue;
}
```

ACTUAL FILES:

tabs.page.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="home">
      <i class="fal fa-home-alt fa-2x"></i>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button [routerLink]="['/tabs/home/feed/feed-user/' + id]">
      <i class="fal fa-user-circle fa-2x"></i>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button [routerLink]="['/tabs/home/trade-room']">
      <i class="fal fa-comments-alt-dollar fa-2x"></i>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

tabs.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
     {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
     },
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: '../home/home.module#HomePageModule'
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

I need some way to change the color button when they are clicked

Comment: I have been stuck with the same error when I added dynamic params to my tabs, so tab classes and values will depend on the params. I used @Rich Tillis 's solution to solve my problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you are looking for but maybe you can use some form of this idea to solve your problem.

You can subscribe to the router events in tabs.page.ts and evaluate the url and apply css if the url matches one of the redirects.

**tabs.page.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterEvent } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tabs.page.scss']
})
export class TabsPage {

  selectedPath = '';

  constructor(private router:Router) { 
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
      if(event && event.url){
        this.selectedPath = event.url;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**tabs.page.html**

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="home">
      <i class="fal fa-home-alt fa-2x"></i>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button [routerLink]="['/tabs/home/feed/feed-user/' + id]" [class.active-item]="selectedPath.includes('feed')">
      <i class="fal fa-user-circle fa-2x"></i>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button [routerLink]="['/tabs/home/trade-room']" [class.active-item]="selectedPath.includes('trade')">
      <i class="fal fa-comments-alt-dollar fa-2x"></i>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

**tabs.page.scss**

```
.active-item {
  color: red;
}
```

This will not affect the existing behavior of the tabs defined in tabs.module.ts. You will probably have to write a bit more to manage the css of those tabs.

I came across this pattern [here](https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-4-tabs-side-menu/) by Simon Grimm. He has some really great tutorials.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem as well. I am using ionic 6 and I am surprised that there is not easier way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the class of the button 'tab-selected' from true to false when you detect the right path.

```
<ion-tab-button [routerLink]="['/tabs/home/feed/feed-user/' + id]" [class.tab-selected]="selectedPath.includes('feed')">
  <i class="fal fa-user-circle fa-2x"></i>
</ion-tab-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-tab-button tab="home" [routerLink]="['/tabs/home/feed/feed-user/' + 
id]">
  <i class="fal fa-user-circle fa-2x"></i>
</ion-tab-button>
```

By principle design.. you should not have nested nested routing child compenent...

tabs/home/1 should be sufficent..
and feed/feed-user should be component residing in home and render without the need to specified as a child route path..