# Ionic tabs button not changing color when selected

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to navigate to a path through tabs but selected tab color not changing when I use

**tabs.html**
`<ion-tab-button [tab]="route">`

**tabs.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getId().get().subscribe((id) => {
        this.route = id;
    });
}
```

but when I remove `[tab]` to `tab` it works fine

I need to get route Id/params from server side.

Comment: What do you need? Do you want to get tab route/id from the server and switch it automatically inside your application?

Comment: @DanilProkhorenkoyes in my case the route is `tabs/tab1/:id` but on clicking the tab bar color is not working.

Comment: yes @DanilProkhorenko

Comment: Found and Solved this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57032449/11728529).

Answer (score 1):

To select programmatically one of the tabs you have at least two options.

**Navigate to the desired tab:**

```
import { IonTabs, NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

// add NavController to your constructor
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {}

// navigate by your route
this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/tabs/tab2');
```

**Select tab:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

// declare child's IonTab inside your component
@ViewChild(IonTabs) tabs: IonTabs;

// select your tab
this.tabs.select('tab2');
```